# Tag rename: [pokemon-sword-and-shield] ->[pokemon-sword-shield]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, pokemon

Can we get [pokemon-sword-and-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-and-shield) renamed to [pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield)? It should be consistent with other Pokémon tags

- [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire)
- [pokemon-sun-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun-moon)
- [pokemon-black-2-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-2-white-2)
- etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, renamed.

I originally created some synonyms back in June, and I just based the main tag off the marketing material at the time.